# Flask + Postgresql and opening/closing a db connection

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

I'm trying to build a simple Flask web application that query a postgres db and inserting/deleting data. I'm even not sure about updating/inserting, but at minimum I'll just query a db. I don't want to use any ORM because it's quite simple. I want to use `psycopg2` since I've used it before in my simple python application. Now I want to know how and when I should open and close a db connection. I've seen this: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/dbcon/ but it didn't find an answer in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlite3/ provides a better example. Its for sqllite, but all that is different is how the initial connection is established. So where it uses `sqllite3`, put your `psycopg2` calls in:

```
import sqlite3
from flask import g

DATABASE = '/path/to/database.db'

@app.before_request
def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    return db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_connection(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()
```

You can find a fully working code example showing use of the db here: https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/examples/flaskr/flaskr/flaskr.py. Note that the example establishing the db connection manually per request in the `@app.route` methods, whereas the example above uses the `@app.before_request` hook to establish it before the route methods are called.

You said you didn't want an ORM, but you can also use `SQLAlchemy` in a non-orm fashion: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html. The benefit of this is that there are specific `session` objects for managing the db connectio: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlalchemy/

Comment: where should `get_db` be called?

Comment: The docs suggest the call should be tied to the current context, which in this case is the request, so putting the `@app.before_request` attribute on the method should do it. I've updated the code sample.

Comment: what's the "g", is it like a session object where I can store variables?

Comment: also, should I close a connection in "@app.teardown_request" or "@app.teardown_appcontext"?

Comment: `g` is the application context: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/appcontext/#the-application-context. According to the docs `app context is created before the request comes in and is destroyed (torn down) whenever the request finishes` so `@app.teardown_context` should be the right place.

Comment: After adding that code I get error: `TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a connection.` So to use that approach `get_db()` cannot return a value (I have commented out `return db` line). In view functions you can then get db connection instance with `g._database`